# Issue running the VMware tools configuration in Ubuntu 17.10 VM

Tags: vmware, 17.10, vmware-tools

When I start the `vmware-config-tools.pl` perl script after the installation,  I receive the message `(process:3679): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_file_test: assertion 'filename != NULL' failed`.

Additionally, the GCC path seems to be invalid and even after installing the `build-essential` package the path to GCC is not found and I'm also not able to enter it manually.